# android sax parser handler

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I have to develop one xml parsing app using sax parser.

I have follows below xml feed:

```
<root>
  <Categories>
        <Category name="Photos">
             <article articleid="4537" title="Sonam-Steals-the-Mai-Show"/>
             <article articleid="4560" title="Big-B-Croons-For-World-Peace"/>
              <article articleid="4585" title="Yami-Paints-The-Town-Red"/>
         </Category>
       <Category name="Style">
             <article articleid="266" title="Dita wows us in a sari"/>
             <article articleid="268" title="Frieda is a natural"/>
             <article articleid="269" title="Demi finds love in Jodhpur"/>
       </Category>
    </Categories>
    </root>
```

Here i have to create one class for getter and setter:

```
public class Laptop {
            private String brand;
            private List<String> model;
          public String getBrand() {
           return brand;
             }

       public void setBrand(String brand) {
               this.brand = brand;
                }
         public List<String> getModel() {
          return model;
           }
        public void setModel(List<String> string) {
          this.model = string;
         }
```

My xml handler look like below code:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    current = true;
        if (localName.equals("Category")) {
        laptop = new Laptop();
        laptop.setBrand(attributes.getValue("name"));

    }

     else if (localName.equals("article")) {
           laptop.setModel(attributes.getValue("title"));
       } 
        }

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if(current)
    {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        current=false;
    }
         }

     public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
          current = false;
      if (localName.equals("Category")) {
          // add it to the list
          laptops.add(laptop);

      } 
    if (localName.equals("article")) {
        laptop.getModel().add(currentValue);
        }
```

Here am getting below error on  these line:

```
           laptop.setModel(attributes.getValue("title"));
```

**The method setModel(List) in the type Laptop is not applicable for the arguments (String)**

How can i resolve that error.please give me solution for these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says yon can not assing a `String` instance to a `List` instance. And it is quite reasonable. Since

```
public void setModel(List<String> string) {
          this.model = string;
}
```

takes a List as parameter.

As possible fix you can try in this way, if you want to keep a `List` of `String` (article) for every Laptop instance

```
public void setModel(String string) {
      if (this.model == null)
           this.model = new List<String>();    
      this.model.add(string);
}
```

Comment: change private List<String> model; to private String model;

Comment: @blackbelt solved above error.but am getting below error The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments 
  (List<String>) on    these line holder.txtModel.setText(laptop.getModel());

Comment: is the same error. If a method requires as parameter a String you can not pass it a List of String. Choose the String you need to display and get it from the List. You should really read the documentation, but first of all you should be clear your mind about what you want to achieve and how. Those are only suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As @blackbelt tried to explain, you can only assign the values which are accepted by a method. `TextView.setText(CharSequence)` accepts a `CharSequence` so you should supply a String, whereas getModel() returns a List of String `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not motivating you to code like this way, but you may avoid the model class and cast your data type inside Handler class like this:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        currentElement = true;
        db = new DatabaseHelper(thecontext);
        if (qName.equals("Asa.Amms.Data.Entity.User")) {
            int length = attributes.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                String name = attributes.getQName(i);
                if (name.equals("Id")) {
                    id = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(i));
                }
                if (name.equals("Login")) {
                    LoginID = attributes.getValue(i).toString();
                }
                if (name.equals("Name")) {
                    Name = attributes.getValue(i).toString();
                }
                if (name.equals("Password")) {
                    Password = attributes.getValue(i).toString();
                }
                if (name.equals("ProgramOfficerId")) {
                    user_ProgramOfficerId = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(i).toString());
                }
            }    
            db.insertUser(id, LoginID, Name, Password, user_ProgramOfficerId);
        }
}
```